# Select from Database with specific on Windows phone app with C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, windows-phone

I have [Table] named Member with 3 [Columns] : FullName | Address | Telephone.
What I want is when I select a "FullName" in the list of "FullName" in a page and then it will  navigate to another page and shows data from just 2 Columns: "FullName" + "Address"   (not including "Telephone")

Following is my code. but when I select "FullName" it shows data from all columns in table. pls help me to fix it

**SelectionChanged** code in **Showlist.xaml**

```
private void Listmember_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MemberDetail.xaml?name=" + (Listmember.SelectedItem as Member).FullName, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

On **Details.xaml** has this code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   string haha = NavigationContext.QueryString["name"];
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
   Details.ItemsSource = DBHelper.GetDetails(haha);
}
```

And here is the **GetDetails()** Function in **DBHelper.cs**:

```
public static IList<Member> GetDetails(string fullname)
{
   IList<Member> ccc;
   using (var context = new NameDataContext(ConnectionString))
   {
      ccc = (from ee in context.Members
         where ee.FullName == fullname
         select ee).ToList();
   }
   return ccc;
}
```

Comment: The problem is in Details.xaml/MemberDetail.xaml.. There, you need to state which column you want show and which are not

Comment: Conituing to post questions, delete them, then repost a duplicate will cause you not to be able to post questions at all, eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Change your GetDetails method with this method and update your ListBox DataTemplate  remove Ui control from ListBox DataTemplate where you bind TelePhoneProperty.

```
public static IList<Member> GetDetails(string fullname)
{
   IList<Member> ccc;
   using (var context = new NameDataContext(ConnectionString))
   {
      ccc = (from ee in context.Members
         where ee.FullName == fullname
         select new Member()
              {
              Address = ee.Address ,
              FullName = ee.FullName 
              }
             ).ToList();
   }
   return ccc;
}
```